# In Monopoly Deal, can I put properties of the same color on the table, but not in a "set"

Tags: monopoly-deal

I want to get properties on the table, but not complete the set. I am trying to avoid having a complete set stolen. I realize by keeping same color cards separate, they could be taken in a forced deal or sly deal, but when it is my turn, I can arrange my properties how I want to collect rent or if I get three complete set, arrange them on my turn for the win. But by keeping the same color cards separate, at least I won't lose an entire set when the deal breaker is played.

Comment: This concept of separation is neither explicit nor implicit in the rules. Once you have *"put down properties into your own collection"*, they are there. Physically placing them close or far does nothing to change their color or number towards a complete set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough to make a set, then you have a set.

From the [compiled FAQ on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2459561/compilation-rules-clarifications):

> If you have more properties of one color than is needed to make a complete property set, you must form as many complete sets as possible, and group the remaining properties of that color together.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties are all mono-color, they are automatically added to the set.

The key piece in the base rules is the rules on playing properties:

> Lay Property cards down in front of you to build up your Property sets.
>
> Each card shows how many properties there are to collect in that color-set.

With a bit of scrutinizing of this section, I think it's reasonable to conclude that colors and sets are synonymous.  As a result, playing a property on the table makes it part of the set.

### What if you have more than the number of properties in the set?

This is one exception, where you can have a second set in the color.  The ruling listed [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2459561/compilation-rules-clarifications) is reasonable, but doesn't provide a source, so I can't tell how authoritative it is:

> If you have more properties of one color than is needed to make a complete property set, you must form as many complete sets as possible, and group the remaining properties of that color together.

(Credit to [L. Scott Johnson](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/53556/9999) for finding this)

### What about wilds?

Wilds are the other exception.  If you have a wild (either 2-color or any-color), it's up to you which color it counts as.  The rules for this are the following:

> You can only reorganize your property collection on your turn.
>
> ...
>
> You can swap [wilds] around amongst different sets on your turn.

So, if at least one of the properties in the prospective set is a wild, you can intentionally not have a set by putting the wild in a different color.

Answer (score 0):

The separate placement of the cards does not affect the status of the card as a set, unless the double card is actually being used as part of a set, having a full set of cards in front of you is considered a set; the card should be placed the 'color you are using' side up:

> You can use these to build Property sets. Choose a color, and play the
> card with that color faceup. You can flip the card to change the color
> of the Property any time on your turn!

In the (non-official) [rules clarifications](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2459561/compilation-rules-clarifications) this is quite clear:

> Keep in mind that Wild Property cards only count as 1 color at a time, so if you have a Baltic Avenue card and a half-brown dual-wild
> property card, you can treat the dual-wild property as its non-brown
> color so that you don’t have to group it with Baltic Avenue (which
> would be vulnerable to a Deal Breaker card). Of course, if you have
> non-wild properties of both colors that are on the dual-wild property
> card, you must group it with one of those properties, as it must be
> treated as exactly 1 of its colors at any given time