# What will happen when someone give me card through forced deal and that card would make complete set. Can he use deal breaker on that?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Let's say I have two green properties of and someone uses Forced Deal on me to take some other card from my side and give me a third green property, which could possibly complete my set of green cards.  Can that person use Deal Breaker on that set in the same turn (as a subsequent action)?

To put it differently, can another player use Forced Deal to force me to complete a set or do I have the choice to not complete the set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Monopoly Deal, can I put properties of the same color on the table, but not in a "set"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53172/in-monopoly-deal-can-i-put-properties-of-the-same-color-on-the-table-but-not-i). TLDR yes, you must group them together and yes, the other player can use a Dealbreaker card on it.

Answer (score -1):

If the property they give you is single-color, then they can take your set with Deal Breaker that turn.  If it is a wild, you have the choice to treat it as a different color.

See my answer over on [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/58265/9999) for the justification.